# "I hope not" vs "I don't hope so"

Tags: difference, grammaticality, sentence-usage, conversation

> *'Is that woman American?'*
> *'I think so. / I don't think so.'*

> *'Do you think it's going to rain?'*
> *'I hope so. / I hope not.'* (**not** *'I don't hope so'*).

We can say *"I don't think so*"; but why can't we say *"I don't hope so"* ?

Comment: I know not. But [in the UK] we _might_ answer "Is that woman American?" with "I think not." Asked "Do you think it's going to rain?", if I were to reply, "I don't hope so", the other person might say, "Of course you don't _hope_ so! Who would want it to rain?!" Asked, "Do you _hope_ it's going to rain?" we might well reply, "I don't _hope_ so, but I think it might."

Answer (score 1):

To say **I hope not** is to express the hope that something will not happen.

For example:
A: I suppose that your son will marry his girlfriend soon.
B: I hope not. She's not suitable.

To say **I don't hope so** is to deny that you do.

For example:
A: Why do you hope to visit Washington in winter?
B: I don't hope so. If I visit the city, it will be in the
spring.

Comment: The twist is that "I don't think it's going to rain" is often used when you mean "I think it's going to be dry". It's "I don't think" that's strange, not "I hope not".